# MySQL query with multiple tables for autocomplete

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got some SQL code which is used for jQuery Autocomplete. At this point there is a query which gets the name of the product:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name AS name
FROM products_names
WHERE (name LIKE '%$q%' AND language_code = 'pl')
  OR (name2 LIKE '%$q%' AND language_code = 'pl')
```

It's working OK, but while typing in search it also shows the names of the products which are disabled.

Information about whether a product is active or disabled is kept in the `status` column of the `products` table.

I need to have a query which will work like the one above, and show the name of the product only if its `status` value is `0`.

The table `products_names` has a field `id_product` storing the product ID; the table `products` stores it in `id`.

Could you give me an example of such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name AS name 
FROM products_names A JOIN products B ON A.id_product = B.id 
WHERE ((name LIKE '%$q%' AND language_code = 'pl') OR (name2 LIKE '%$q%' AND language_code = 'pl')) AND status = 0
```